# JPA2 Provider as Hibernate in Weblogic 12.1

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, weblogic12c

I am getting below exception when we try to deploy our application with JPA2 Provider as Hibernate in weblogic 12.1

```
   Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:92)

    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:57)
```

I have below entries in weblogic.xml :

```
        <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>

        <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>

    </prefer-application-packages>
```

and below pre class path setting in weblogic server commEnv.cmd (common/bin).

```
 set PRE_CLASSPATH=%MW_HOME%\modules\javax.persistence_2.0.0.0_2-0.jar;
```

Application works fine in weblogic 11g with below pre class path setting.

PRE_CLASSPATH="/apps/Oracle/Middleware/modules/javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar:/apps/Oracle/Middleware/modules/com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar"

There was as addition jar com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar. This jar is missing in weblogic 12.1 modules directory.

Could anyone suggest how to resolve the persistence provider conflict issue in weblogic 12.1 ?

Hibernate Jar Versions : hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar, hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final.jar

Answer (score 3):

It worked after removing below package from weblogic.xml

```
 <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
```

Also PRE_CLASSPATH setting is not required for 12c